# How to call OnTriggerEnter less frequently?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I have a game that I have been developing and it requires the `OnTriggerEnter()` to be called many times with many different `GameObjects`. Although it is called a lot, I don't need it to be called extremely frequently. So, I was wondering if it is possible to lower how often the method is called such as calling it every other update or even less often than that. Is this possible?

Comment: this method (OnTriggerEnter) can run async or not ?

Comment: I don't believe it can run async, but I could be wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check trigger collisions manually with functions like [Physics.CheckBox](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.CheckBox.html).

Put it in a slow coroutine and cache the result of the collision, so you can always check the last state of it.

Answer (score 0):

Still in early phase of learning both Unity and C#, but this came up in an excercise and might be the answer to your problem ?

**from :https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html**

By default, a coroutine is resumed on the frame after it yields but it is also possible to introduce a time delay using WaitForSeconds:

This can be used as a way to spread an effect over a period of time, but it is also a useful optimization. Many tasks in a game need to be carried out periodically and the most obvious way to do this is to include them in the Update function. However, this function will typically be called many times per second. When a task doesn’t need to be repeated quite so frequently, you can put it in a coroutine to get an update regularly but not every single frame. An example of this might be an alarm that warns the player if an enemy is nearby.

To set a coroutine running, you need to use the StartCoroutine function: